# how to show notify to current account if this account is logged in another computer

Tags: wcf

I have a windows application and it connected to a server via WCF services, database is on the server. To using this software, you have to login. So I want to show a notify to UserA, who is working on the software, if UserA's account is logged (on another computer) by another people.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Make your logon service operation on the service return a flag which indicates if this account is being used concurrently by another user.

```
// Pseudocode
LogonResponse response = Service.Logon :> username, password;
if response.UserAccountIsAlreadyLoggedOn print "User logged on already!"
```

To do this the service would have to persist the logged-on state of all users, probably in the database.

Your logon service operation would need to query the logged-on state of the user account being presented by the operation caller.

```
// Pseudocode
public LogonResponse Logon (string username, string password)
{
    if database.IsThisAccountAlreadyLoggedOn :> username ? 
        return LogonResponse :> UserAccountIsAlreadyLoggedOn = true;
    otherwise
        return LogonResponse :> UserAccountIsAlreadyLoggedOn = false;
}
```

This is the easiest way I can think of to proceed with this.